# How to install FamilySearch Indexing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk

How can I install FamilySearch Indexing on Ubuntu 16.04? When running the installation script found at https://indexing.familysearch.org/downloads/Indexing_unix.sh the prompt says that Java 1.6 is required, but openjdk-6-jre is deprecated? Is it possible to install with a newer version of Java?

Comment: Which software exactly and how are you trying to install it? Maybe there's a way around that hard dependency on OpenJDK 6 and the program can run fine with OpenJDK 8. After all, Java applications are supposed to be compatible with later runtime environment releases.

Comment: Familysearch indexing.  Technically its only supported on 32 bit linux but I was able to install it on Ubuntu 14.04 using the script in this repository https://github.com/zvakanaka/family-search-ubuntu.  I upgraded to version 8 of Java on my system and just changed a few lines in the launch script to get it to work, but now I'm trying to install it on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 install and can't figure out how to install familysearch without openjdk-6-jre

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I just got the application to work by installing the PPA for java 6 described in this thread: https://github.com/zvakanaka/family-search-ubuntu/issues/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I documented my attempt in [Family Search for Linux patch set for any JVM ≥ 1.6](https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/a7eb57becee7d5c44a3f5d9df89e2a78) :

> ## Family Search for Linux patch set for any JVM ≥ 1.6
>
> ### Prerequisites
>
> You can install all of the following packages with a single `apt install` command. I just listed them here separately to explain each of them.
>
> - A Java runtime environment of at least version 1.6. On Debian you
>     can install one like this:
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt install default-jre
>   ```
> - According to [Getting FamilySearch Indexing to work in Ubuntu
>     14.04](http://tuxrocket.com/2014/07/21/getting-familysearch-indexing-to-work-in-ubuntu-14-04/)
>     you also need a few shared libraries:
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libxi6 libxtst6 libxrender1
>   ```
>
>   They were already installed on my system so I haven't tested the veracity of that claim.
> - The `wget` and `patch` tools:
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt install wget patch
>   ```
>
> ### Installation instructions
>
> 1. Download the Unix installer.
>
>    ```
>    wget -c https://indexing.familysearch.org/downloads/Indexing_unix.sh
>    ```
> 2. Download the patch set.
>
>    ```
>    wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/davidfoerster/a7eb57becee7d5c44a3f5d9df89e2a78/raw/Indexing_unix.sh.patch https://gist.githubusercontent.com/davidfoerster/a7eb57becee7d5c44a3f5d9df89e2a78/raw/indexing.patch
>    ```
> 3. Patch the installer.
>
>    ```
>    patch -b Indexing_unix.sh < Indexing_unix.sh.patch
>    ```
> 4. Run the installer.
>
>    ```
>    ./Indexing_unix.sh
>    ```
> 5. Patch the installed application.
>
>    ```
>    patch -p2 -d ~/.FamilySearchIndexing < indexing.patch
>    ```
>
> … and you're good to go.
>
> Tested with OpenJDK 1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution no longer works, the installation still works fine but the program has errors when trying to use it.  I contacted their support and was able to get on a beta test for the new, long awaited web app